# Pullback of representations along the Cayley embedding?

Tags: reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

Given a finite group, $G$, the Cayley embedding gives us a map $G\to S_{|G|}$. The representations of the symmetric group are particularly well understood, so it stands to reason that the restriction functor (along the Cayley embedding) is at least a mechanical way to generate representations of $G$.

Has this been studied?  Are there interesting things to say, e.g., under what conditions this generates all irreps of $G$, or conditions on $G$ which cause the representations to be trivial?  Since $|G|!$ is significantly larger than $|G|$, I would expect this not to be a practical avenue for computation, but are there insights to be gained from this approach?

**N.B.** This question was inspired from the fact that if $|G|=2n$ with $n$ odd, then the restriction of the sign representation is nontrivial, and hence its kernel gives an index $2$ subgroup.  I suppose that I am looking for a good perspective that would encompass this result?

Comment: Today I was wondering something similar. Have you thought about it a bit more 4 years later?

Answer (score 1):

It s true that (when $S_{|G|}$ is identified in the obvious way with the group of $|G| \times |G|$ permutation matrices- that is, matrices with just one entry non-zero entry ( a 1) on each row and column) the Cayley embedding (composed with the above embedding into the group of matrices, affords the regular representation of $G$. For each irreducible complex character $\chi$ of $G$, the regular representation has exactly $\chi(1)$ (equivalent) irreducible summands affording character $\chi$ (when decomposed as a direct sum of irreducible representations).

However, knowledge of the regular representation afforded by the Cayley embedding alone is not usually enough to complete the decomposition of the regular representation into a direct sum of irreducibles.